# change the sorter icon in ant design table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I wanted to change the sorter up and down icon in ant design table component ,but i could not find any attributes or props in ant design docs.
I found the way to change the filter icon by using `filterIcon` props on table column.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Chinese Score',
    dataIndex: 'chinese',
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.chinese - b.chinese,
      multiple: 3,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out if any one is looking for answer :

```
const columns=[{
      title: (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          Publish Books <SortIcon style={{ marginLeft: "8px" }} />
        </div>
      ),
      dataIndex: "publishedBooks",
      sorter: {
        compare: (a, b) => a.publishedBooks - b.publishedBooks,
        multiple: 4,
      },
    },
]
```

Comment: but it's showing default sort icon as well(showing both custom and default sort icons)

Comment: You can remove the default icon by using 
.ant-table-column-sorter {
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can configure title field and hide default sort icon

```js
const columns = [{
  key: "name",
  title: (titleProps) => {
    const sortedColumn = titleProps.sortColumns?.find(({ column }) => column.key === "name");

    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "spaceBetween" }}>
       some title
       {sortedColumn?.order === 'ascend' ? <SortUpIcon /> : <SortDownIcon />}
     </div>
    )
  }
}]
```

css

```
.ant-table-column-sorter {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding more on what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table#column), is now possible to change the sort icon, using the `sortIcon` prop.

Here is an example:

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        sorter: (a: Data, b: Data) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
        sortIcon: ({ sortOrder }) => <SortArrows order={sortOrder} />,
    },
    {
...
```